# Выделение в ListView

Tags: android, listview, java

Есть ListView, в нем 4 пункта. Как программно сделать проверку? Если выбран 0 пункт, то делаем это, если выбран пункт 1, то это...

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            Если выбран 0. То для 0 пункта ставить текст ПРИВЕТ. Если выбран 1 то для 1 ставим ПРИВЕТ, а у 0 и у всех возвращяем к исходному значению. исходное значение Пока
        }
    });
```

Comment: @asdasdasd, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Свичом по `position`.

Comment: По postion установить текст. а убрать то как?

Comment: Ну, что скажите?

Comment: @asdasdasd, что именно убрать ?

Comment: Кому? )))... вы меня не понимаете, видимо. )

Comment: @asdasdasd, присвоить null/"" тому, чему до этого был присвоен текст.

Comment: @asdasdasd заполняйте `ArrayList` (или что у Вас там) и обновляйте `adapter` у `listview`.

Comment: Я не понимаю. ( Можно пример с поправкой моего кода?

Comment: @asdasdasd если вы выбираете `position == x`, то необходимо пересоздать список, чтобы у него `x`-элементом было слово "Привет" (остальные "Пока") и обновить адаптер "adapter.notifyDataSetChange()"

Comment: А как пересоздать адаптер. я умею только обновлять. notifity вот так. а пересоздавать? и будет ли из за этого тормозить?